# Can I have in my bibliography parentheses for editors "(eds.):" when I use the innamebeforetitle option, but ", eds." when I cite them directly?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Finally I almost have my perfect citation style when I cite an `@incollection` entry.

> Author (year). “Title”. In: Editor A and Editor B (Hrsg.): Title

So important is the "(Hrsg.):" in parentheses.
But when I cite the collection directly I would like to have it without parentheses and with an comma before it (otherwise it looks dumb when I use the author-year-style)

> Editor A, Editor B, Hrsg. (year). Title.

So here is a minimal example, perhaps someone has a nice solution - would be so helpful!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,
style=ext-authoryear-icomp,innamebeforetitle,innameidem=true]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{editor = (Hrsg\adddot):}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{editors = (Hrsg\adddot):}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@incollection{Hoffmann.2010,
 author = {Hoffmann, Thomas},
 title = {Erste Natur, Zweite Natur und das Gute f{\"u}r den Menschen},
 pages = {75--104},
 editor = {Hoffmann, Thomas and Reuter, Michael},
 booktitle = {Nat{\"u}rlich gut. Aufs{\"a}tze zur Philosophie von Philippa Foot},
 year = {2010},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main (u. a.)}
}


@book{Hoffmannetal.2010,
 year = {2010},
 title = {Nat{\"u}rlich gut. Aufs{\"a}tze zur Philosophie von Philippa Foot},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main (u. a.)},
 editor = {Hoffmann, Thomas and Reuter, Michael}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Hoffmann.2010} \cite{Hoffmannetal.2010}



\printbibliography[]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting like parentheses and trailing punctuation like colons should never be included in bibstrings and their translations.

In this case the right way to make the changes is via the `editortype` field format, the `editortypedelim` delimiter and the `innametitledelim` delimiter.

`biblatex-ext`'s `bbx:in:editor` macro (which prints the editor for `innamebeforetitle`) reuses the `editortype` field format, which is also used by other macros to print the editor string. So the easiest way to obtain different formatting is by overriding the global setting locally in `bbx:in:editor`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,
style=ext-authoryear-icomp,innamebeforetitle,innameidem=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{innametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:in:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{##1}}%
     \DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}%
     \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:innameidem} and test {\bbx@ineditoridem}}
       {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
       {\printnames[ineditor]{editor}}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}
\makeatother


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Hoffmann.2010,
 author   = {Hoffmann, Thomas},
 title    = {Erste Natur, Zweite Natur und das Gute für den Menschen},
 pages    = {75--104},
 crossref = {Hoffmannetal.2010},
}
@collection{Hoffmannetal.2010,
 year     = {2010},
 title    = {Natürlich gut},
 subtitle = {Aufsätze zur Philosophie von Philippa Foot},
 address  = {Frankfurt am Main and others},
 editor   = {Hoffmann, Thomas and Reuter, Michael}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Hoffmann.2010} \cite{Hoffmannetal.2010}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Hofmann,Thomas(2010).“Erste Natur, Zweite Natur und das Gute für den Menschen”. In: Thomas Hofmann und Michael Reuter (Hrsg.): Natürlich gut. Aufsätze zur Philosophie von Philippa Foot. Frankfurt am Main u.a., S. 75–104.//Hofmann, Thomas und Michael Reuter, Hrsg. (2010). Natürlich gut. Aufsätze zur Philosophie von Philippa Foot. Frankfurt am Main.]

Note the small changes to your example entries: With `biblatex` and Biber you can use non-ASCII characters like `ü` directly, you don't have to escape them to `{\"u}`. You can also avoid repetition with the `crossref` feature. Finally, the parent entry should be a `@collection` and not a `@book` (after all the child is an `@incollection` and not an `@inbook`).

Comment: oh wow, thank you so much! Very impressive

Comment: @Horstfuchs If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the green checkmark on the top left to mark the question as resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: ah thank you!!!